# How to find MULTIPLE duplicated elements that meet the criteria?

Tags: python

I have an array, full of numbers including ones that are duplicated.

An example would be: 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10

I want to find numbers that are duplicated exactly two times, regardless of the number itself.

What would be needed to go about this idea?

Comment: Well, given a number, can you write code to tell how many times it's duplicated? Did you try to write any code at all to solve the problem? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `set` and the method `count` of `lists`, for example:

```
data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10]

duplicates = { number for number in set(data) if data.count(number) == 2 }
print(duplicates)
>>> {2, 5}
```

Comment: I'd suggest a minor tweak to keep the runtime down a bit if there are likely to be a non-trivial number of duplicates, just iterating over the unique items in `data`, by making it `{number for number in set(data) if data.count(number) == 2}`. At the cost of `O(n)` precheck work, you reduce the work from `O(n²)` to `O(n*m)` where `n` is total items, and `m` is number of unique items. For an input like `[1] * 100`, this reduces work from 101 iterations over `data` to just two.

Comment: Thank you marcos and ShadowRanger for the solutions! I now know how to go about the situation - as I'm a beginner to python (and coding) - and appreciate the information behind as to why ShadowRanger's solution is faster than marcos. Thank you all so much again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The asymptotically fastest approach here is [using `collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to cheaply get the counts for every element, then use a listcomp to filter it to those with the desired count:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10]
exactly_two = [item for item, count in Counter(data).items() if count == 2]

print(exactly_two)
```

This is `O(n)` to create the `Counter` (in total input items) and `O(m)` to filter it (where `m` is number of unique items); since `m` is derived `n`, overall work remains `O(n)`, beating solutions based on `.count` (which is `O(n²)` since each `count` fully iterates `data`).